# Best way to solve typescript "Interface | {}"

Tags: typescript

For example I have this object:

`const car: Car | {} = {}`

And for `car` I have:

```
interface Car {
    uuid: string;
    name: string;
    ...
}
```

And in code when I write `car.name` I receive the error "Property name does not exist on type {}.

How can I solve this without typing everywhere in code

`(car as Car).name`
?

Comment: As long as ` | {}` is in there there's nothing you can do. Why do you need ` | {}`?

Comment: `const car: Car | {} = {}` is a fairly unusual thing. You can't reassign `car` to point to something else, so the only way to make it a `Car` is to add properties to it, which largely defeats the purpose of having a static type system (TypeScript) in the code. But TypeScript does accommodate that in various ways. You might consider `const car: Partial<Car> = {};` instead. That makes all of the properties of `Car` optional (as though it were defined as `interface Car { uuid?: string; name?: string; /*...*/ }`.

Comment: Because the value for `car` comes from an api call. Until that call is made the `car` is an empty object.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Right, this fixed my problem thank you. Making everything optional

Comment: @Roland - Glad that helped! :-)